# How to store HStore field properly?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-postgresql

Here I have a `HStoreField` which will be taken from user Input.

User gives the input in the format `s:Small,l:Large,` But I think the `HStoreField` needs the data type like this`{'s': 'Small','l':'Large'}`.

How can I covert the user data into this format so that I can store into the `HStoreField`.

Or simply I need to store the data. How can I do it ?

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
      properties = HStoreField()

# view 
properties = request.POST.get('properties')
print(properties)

#properties has data in this format s:Small,l:Large,

MyModel.objects.create(properties=properties)
```

I get the error like this.

```
django.db.utils.InternalError: Unexpected end of string
LINE 1: ...antity_reserved") VALUES ('ttt', 11, 'ttt', '55', 'Small:rrr...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parse the properties string and create dictionary from it:

```py
properties = 's:Small,l:Large,'

properties_dict = {}
for pair in properties[:-1].split(','):
    key, value = pair.split(':')
    properties_dict[key] = value

>>> print(properties_dict)
{'s': 'Small', 'l':'Large'}
```

Comment: I got the ValueError `not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)` from this line `key, value = pair.split(':')`

Comment: Please, show your properties string, on which you get the error

Comment: `s:Small,l:Large,` this is my properties tring format. It has comma at the end also

Comment: The code i posted works correctly on Python3.8.5, linux. Check your string with properties

Comment: If string has comma at the and, just take the slice `[:-1]`. I update my answer, try it